# Bash: a read-only associative array that can be modified but not extended

Tags: bash

I would like to initialize an array with a set of keys and values, such that values may be changed but no new keys may be added.

Comment: Unless something in latest BASH version I don't believe any such BASH array is available.

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it directly. As a substitute you can have a read-only associative array with keys (indices) into another, non-read-only array which keeps values.

This way there would be no way to add new keys to the front array and even though it would be possible to add new keys to the back array they wouldn't be reachable via front array keys.

Something like this:

```
declare -r -A front=([a]=0 [b]=1 [c]=2)
declare -a back=(alpha beta gamma)
# Read
echo "${back[front[a]]}"
# Write
back[front[a]]="ALPHA"
# Iterate
for k in "${!front[@]}"; do echo "$k = ${back[front[$k]]}"; done
```

You can then wrap this into a function interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `readonly` to mark it as completely readonly:

```
$ declare -A x
$ x=([foo]=hello [bar]=world)
$ readonly -A x
$ x[baz]=zap
bash: x: readonly variable
```

But that would also remove your ability to change the existing values.

The feature you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: As per OP `such that values may be changed but no new keys may be added.`